# PLSQL - Fastest way to check for dups before insert

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, duplicates, primary-key

(Using Oracle) I have a table with one column (myCol) which is the primary key.

When doing an insert, is it faster to check with a select statement before doing the insert or just write the insert and let error handling check it?

So would this be faster?

```
BEGIN

SELECT count(*) INTO v_count FROM myTbl WHERE myCol = v_newVal;

IF v_count = 0 THEN
     INSERT INTO myTbl (myCol) VALUES (v_newVal);
END IF;

END;
```

or this?

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO myTbl (myCol) VALUES (v_newVal);

EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
     null;

END;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance, certainly the second option is better.

But, more importantly, the first option has a bug - it will fail in cases where more than one session tries to insert the same value at the same time - one of them will succeed, the other session will wait for the first to commit and then raise DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX (which you haven't handled).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try merge. Typically you should avoid count() from dup checking. There is also a hint you can use to ignore duplicates. This page gives a nice example of this.

http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2010/1/1/the-11gr2-ignore_row_on_dupkey_index-hint.html

Comment: well I disagree with that part, but it was intended to show the query hint approach that's all... when tables get big count can get expensive. Unless your table is big, the count route is the simplest.

Comment: The count can be expensive and it can ruin cache of other future selects since lots of records will be parsed and read.

Start without count() only make it more complicated if you have an actual performance problem.

Finally even if you do count() you still need the exception handling because of parallelism

Comment: If you are inserting a single value it will be very fast either way. The way to make it very fast is to batch insert lots of values or insert from a select query. What you are optimizing here is peanuts in my experience